# Add prefix to link url

Tags: php, permalinks

I want to add image link on wordpress site which redirect the user to the another page of same url but with different prefix. for example
page url is mydomain.com/post1234 when user click the image on this page it redirect the user to the url mydomain.com/md/post1234

The following code print the current page url on every post page on site but i want to add "md" prefix in the url

```
<a href="<?php
$Path=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$URI='http://www.example.com'.$Path;
?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/sgxx.png">Click Here</a>
```

Pls suggest the correct code to do this.

Comment: Both of questions are related to permalinks structure. I don't want to change permalinks. I want to add image link on header of all pages which redirect the user of current page url but with prefix like
current page url : http://example.com/post1234
redirect page url: http://example.com/md/post1234

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [question about retrieving Wordpress post slug](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42117/how-to-retrieve-the-slug-of-current-page), you could put together a link like the following:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/md/<?php global $post; echo $post->post_name; ?>">link text</a>
```

Whether that goes to a functioning page or not, I don't know. It seems like you may want to change rewrite rules in the functions but I'm not sure from what you've said.

By the way, you may want to read [why links that only say 'Click here' are bad practice](http://dotmonster.co/blog/why-using-click-here-for-links-is-bad-practice) for SEO and accessibility.