# Category posts show on local install, they do not show on live server

Tags: posts, categories, frontpage

Puzzled to see posts in category are showing on local XAMPP server, however they do not show on the live server. Here is the code to display the category posts.

It is a really simple one pager with links to each of the sections.
`front-page.php` holds the template-parts to each of the sections. `index.php` decides if there is a static page or a category page and serves the corresponding template. In the folder `template-parts` I have `category-photos.php` that displays the photos posts.

Like I said, local version runs just fine. On the `front-page.php` all the posts from all the sections display fine. In the `photos` section the posts also show, on the `front-page.php` but also on the individual category page, meaning `example.com/photos` does show the photos posts locally just fine.

I also comment each of the php files with `<!-- category-photos.php -->` at the top so that I can see in the source if the file is loaded. Locally it shows up in the source, on the live server the `category-photos.php` is not even included in the source on the category page, but indeed on the front page.

I use [WordPress Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) to backup and copy the WordPress installation, the theme files and the database exactly as it is to the live host. The photos posts also show on the `front-page.php` of the live page, however not on the category page, `example.com/photos`. Must say I tried with theme `twentyseventeen` and there the category photos posts display fine of course. What am I doing wrong please?

Have no idea where to start looking for errors. Had a chat with support of the hosting company and they said I might have forgotten to include the category in the menu, but I did include it, .. and they have no clue either apart from that.
If it helps I will try and make a public repo of the theme as well as upload to a live dummy server.

**index.php**

```
<?php
get_header();

global $wp_query;
$pagename = $wp_query->queried_object->post_name;

// checking if it is a static page or category page
// if the $pagename variable is empty get the category
if(empty($pagename)):
  $current_cat = single_cat_title("", false);
  // get the template for photos, category-photos.php
  get_template_part('template-parts/category', $current_cat);
else:
// else it is a static page
$args = array(
  'pagename' => $pagename
);
  $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
      // get the template with corresponding page
      get_template_part( 'template-parts/page', $pagename );
      endwhile;
    endif;
  wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
get_footer();
?>
```

**front-page.php**

```
<?php
get_header();
  // the the template for the photos category, so category-photos.php
  get_template_part( 'template-parts/category', 'photos');  
get_footer();
?>
```

**category-photos.php**

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'photos',
    'post_type' => 'post'
);
// loop over the category photos posts
$query = new WP_Query($args);

echo '<div class="photos-wrap">';
if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
  the_title();
  the_content();     
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Where does it fail? Does category-photos.php never get included? Does the query not return any results? I assume the database is identical on live & dev?

Comment: Yes the db is identical, `category-photos.php` is not included on the live server on the category page, `example.com/photos` but indeed on the front page, where all the photos posts appear fine. So this means the photos posts are there in the db but for some reason are not showing on the category page.

Comment: Can you add the code for the categories page where it should get included?

Comment: It is there in `index.php` starting with `if(empty($pagename)):` then get the current category and then `get_template_part('template-parts/category', $current_cat);`, this pulls in the file `category-photos.php` and there it loops through the photos posts with a simple `WP_Query` using `$args` for `photos` and `post` as `post_type`. This **is** what is so puzzling to me, I think I am including the template files right and calling the loops OK. Locally the photos posts show on the front page and photos category page fine. So for me this means I am including the `category-photos` template fine.

Comment: Are you sure there is no other template that gets preferred over index.php, say archive-photos.php, archive.php etc pp? Does it get into the block following `if(empty($pagename)):`?

Comment: Yes, 100% sure. No there is no other template. Yes is gets into that block after `if(empty($pagename)):` locally just fine. Do you want to have a look at the theme source files? It is a tiny one page project with links to separate pages from each of the sections on the front page, happy to send it to you or even make it public somewhere.

Comment: I'm afraid that won't really help without the database. What does `var_export($wp_query->queried_object)` get you for archives?

Comment: Adding it to `index.php` gets me this: `WP_Term::__set_state(array( 'term_id' => 8, 'name' => 'Photos', 'slug' => 'photos', 'term_group' => 0, 'term_taxonomy_id' => 8, 'taxonomy' => 'category', 'description' => '', 'parent' => 0, 'count' => 3, 'filter' => 'raw', 'cat_ID' => 8, 'category_count' => 3, 'category_description' => '', 'cat_name' => 'Photos', 'category_nicename' => 'photos', 'category_parent' => 0, ))` on the category photos page, meaning `example.com/photos` and it gets me nothing on the front page.

Comment: Does it work if you check `get_class($wp_query->queried_object)` instead of trying the attribute?

Comment: If I put `$test0 = get_class($wp_query->queried_object); var_export($test);` I get `NULL`, if I put `$test1 = get_class($wp_query->queried_object->post_name); var_export($test1);` I get `Warning: get_class() called without object from outside a class` on the index.php page. Hey I could share the code on a c9.io public workspace and invite you to check it out if you like. I am also going to make a WP install from scratch including deleting the db to be 100% sure it has not something to do with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67494/discussion-between-janh2-and-lowtechsun).

Answer (score 0):

After having [**a really good chat that taught me a lot**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67494/discussion-between-janh2-and-lowtechsun) with [janh2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/129206/janh2) we have come up with this solution that got rid of the issue. Read trough the chat to learn from my mistake(s).

Instead of going about it the way I did use this approach, much **less** code and it will work on the live server also.

Since WP automatically looks for a `category-$slug.php` file if you are on an archive (category) page create a file named `category.php` in the theme root folder. In that `category.php` get the current category.

Since I have my `category-photos.php` in the `template-parts` folder I get the current category of the archive page and then use that to get the template for it from the `template-parts` folder.

**category.php**

```
$current_category = sanitize_post( $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object() );
$category_slug = $current_category->slug;  
get_template_part('template-parts/category', $category_slug);
```

**category-photos.php**

```
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'photos',
    'post_type' => 'post'
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
      the_title();
      the_content();
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Since static and other pages use `index.php` if there are no other template files I can write this code below in there. I understand that once there is a `category-$slug.php` or `page-$slug.php` WordPress will automatically use that. Again since I have my page templates in folder `template-parts` I only need this in `index.php` and be done with it.

**index.php**

```
 get_header();
 $current_page = sanitize_post( $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object() );
 $pagename = $current_page->post_name;
   get_template_part( 'template-parts/page', $pagename );
 get_footer();
```

For reference, I use [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188945/77054) for getting the queried object with the correct data.