# wp_dequeue_style and wp_dequeue_script not working on server but does work on local xampp

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, scripts

This is my entire code and it is working perfectly in my local system xampp but not working on server.

```
function taqyeem_dequeue_scrips() {

   if(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])=='my_page' || basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])=='')
    {
            wp_dequeue_style( 'taqyeem-style' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'taqyeem-main' );
            wp_deregister_script( 'comment-reply' );



    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'taqyeem_dequeue_scrips' );

function dequeue_scrips() {


if(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])=='my_page')
    {
            //css

            wp_dequeue_style( 'taxonomy-image-plugin-public' );
            wp_dequeue_style( 'job-alerts-frontend' );
            wp_dequeue_style('validate-engine-css');
            wp_dequeue_style('cp-shortcode');
            wp_dequeue_style('wsl-widget');
            wp_dequeue_style('wp-job-manager-applications-frontend');
            wp_dequeue_style('wp-job-manager-bookmarks-frontend');
            wp_dequeue_style('wp-job-manager-resume-frontend');



            wp_dequeue_style('wp-job-manager-frontend');

            wp_dequeue_style('cp-widgets-css');
            wp_dequeue_style('responsive-css');
            wp_dequeue_style('owl-css');
            wp_dequeue_style('svg-css');
            wp_dequeue_style('cp-burgermenucss');
            wp_dequeue_style('law-bx-slider-css');
            wp_dequeue_style('prettyPhoto');
            wp_dequeue_style('cp-bootstrap');
            wp_dequeue_style('cp-wp-commerce');

            wp_dequeue_style('cp-bx-slider');

            wp_dequeue_style('googleFonts');
            wp_dequeue_style('googleFonts-heading');
            wp_dequeue_style('menu-googleFonts-heading');
            wp_dequeue_style('wppb_stylesheet');
            wp_dequeue_style('A2A_SHARE_SAVE');

            //Script
            wp_dequeue_script( 'html5shiv' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'cp-bootstrap' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'addtoany' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'cp-owl-js' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'cp-velocity' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'owl-kenburns' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'cp-burgermenu' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'cp-burgermenucustom' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'cp-bx-slider' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'cp-custom' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'prettyPhoto' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'cp-pscript' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'cp-scripts_modernizr' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'cp-scripts' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'cp-scripts-workmark' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'cp-easing' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'cp-bx-slider' );

    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_scrips' );
```

Any suggestion please. I am working to improve Google Page Speed to get atleast 90  score in mobile and desktop. Currently itis poor in mobile (56 )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dequeue scripts & styles for a specific page based on the **slug** of the page. You can get the slug in various ways and use it instead of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Use  **`if( is_page( array( 'my_page')`** instead of `if(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])=='my_page')`

```
function wpse_289574_dequeue_scrips() {
   if(is_page( array( 'my_page')){
       wp_dequeue_style( 'taxonomy-image-plugin-public' );
       ...       
   }
}
```

**How to get the slug of a page:**

```
$qo = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object();
$cp = sanitize_post($qo);
$slug = $cp->post_name;
```

Taken from: [How to retrieve the slug of current page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/42117/43098)

```
function wpse_289574_dequeue_scrips() {
   if($slug =='my_page'){
       wp_dequeue_style( 'taxonomy-image-plugin-public' );
       ...       
   }
}
```

Current hook to dequeue is `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Comment: I tried to echo $slug; but its not working.

Comment: I tried is_page() and it is not working in my functions.php file so I used that method.

Comment: $slug outputs nothing

Comment: Yeah! The script handler are absolutely correct. and few works with init hook and rest with wp_enqueue_scripts

Comment: is_page('my_page') not working

Comment: this is the solution for is_page : add_action('get_header', function() {
    if ( is_page( 'my_page' ) ) {    
   
       echo 'This is My page';
 }
});

Comment: I don't think there is `get_header` action hook in WP by default?

Comment: but it is working. but still no idea why dequeue thing not working on live server. and sorry I cant share the URL :(

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code which is working for me:

```
add_action('get_header', function() {
    if ( is_page( 'my_page' ) ) {    
   add_action( 'init', 'taqyeem_dequeue_scrips' );
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_scrips' );

    }
});
```